# Zikula 1.3.9 News module not accepting google async script

Tags: zikula

I am using Zikula 1.3.9 but cannot get async Google ad script to work on News module. The script appears on screen as in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Any script tags inside user content is blocked by default to prevent XSS attacks.

You have at least two options:

1. Add your ad script to the News template file instead of the content.
2. Allow script tags in the security center (only if you trust all your editors).

Comment: Thanks Guite but I had already allowed script as I am the only person contributing to the site. This leaves me with your other suggestion but I do not know which news template file I need to edit. Can you help please.

Comment: I think `modules/News/templates/user/articlecontent.tpl` would be the correct entrypoint.

Comment: Thanks Guite, I'll give it a try tomorrow